# Loop to transfer values to bottom of range is erroneously overwriting values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range, used as a raw data dump from another macro. In this range, I want the vba to go through certain columns (column Q), when the criteria is 1, copy the target range and move to the bottom of a table. I don't know the vba for the table, so just identified the last row, added 1 to paste at the bottom of the table since the table will automatically resize.

My code does everything I need except the following: each instance it finds, it is pasting at the bottom...but as it loops, it overwrites the last entry that was made at the bottom of the table instead of finding the new row and pasting below. I tried adding a sleep timer, and this is how i was able to see it overwriting but it did not resolve the issue.

Data dump range:
Columns W to AC
Values start at row 4 to whatever last row is from data dump.
Column X - Criteria column, either 0 or 1. If 1 then data needs to be moved.
Columns X through AA, of the criteria =1 is being moved from this area, to the Table.

Table starts A3 for headers and down to row 309. If I have 5 entries from data dump, then I expect those values to be pasted below the table, starting in column C. Therefore expanding the row from 309 to 313.

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal milliseconds As Long)

Sub test1()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim TargtRng As Range

    With Sheets("Data_Rates")
        lastrow = Worksheets("Data_Rates").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For Each Cell In .Range("X4:X" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Cell.Value = "1" Then
                '.Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(, 3)).Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow, "C")
                Set TargtRng = .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(, 3))
                .Range(Cells(lastrow, "C"), Cells(lastrow, "E")).Resize(TargtRng.Rows.Count, TargtRng.Columns.Count).Value = TargtRng.Cells.Value
                Sleep (500)
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In the range you are pasting, columns C-E, is there always something in column C? If not, lastrow will not be increasing.

Comment: There is a table, Column C in the table does not contain values. The code above finds the last row, at row 308, adds 1, and inserts at row 309 correctly. It's just that it pastes all 4 instances one on top of the other...so I can watch each value getting copied to 309 rather than the list expanding to 310, 311,312, etc.

Comment: Additionally, the original table, column C was pasting Dates - I modified the structure of the table, because I was trying to copy over and transfer the values of a non-contiguous range...couldn't get it to work, so I restructured. 

Even when I was coping only the first 2 columns, which worked before I restructured Column C to be blanks instead of the dates, it worked but same issue encountered - it kept overwriting the last row with each cell from the loop and the last occurrence is what remained at bottom of table.

Comment: If you use `.Cells(lastrow, "C").Resize(TargtRng.Rows.Count, TargtRng.Columns.Count).Value = TargtRng.Cells.Value` does it work?

Comment: So remove Set TargtRng through Sleep and apply the code change you recommended? I'll try that and let you know - one moment

Comment: Duh have only just noticed that your line assigning `lastrow` is outside your loop. I needs to be after the If line.

Comment: I just tried that, and the macro runs - but it's causing the same issue. The last row keeps getting overwritten. So instead of 4 rows being copied over to the bottom, 1 row is added which reflects the values of the 4thlast row to be copied.

To me - it seemed like it's not recognizing the new last row prior to continued to the next cell in the loop. Or it's running too fast - but I tried adding a sleep to it, and that's how i was able to watch it overwrite in slow motion.

Comment: Let me move the last row

Comment: I've suggested some code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, slightly simplified, but most importantly with the last row variable inside the loop so that it updates as you copy more data across.

```
Sub test1()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim TargtRng As Range

With Sheets("Data_Rates")
    For Each Cell In .Range("X4:X" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = 1 Then
            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(lastrow, "C").Resize(, 4).Value = Cell.Resize(, 4).Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```